# Create table view programmatically with parameters - swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, lazy-loading

When I create table view like this, parameters background color, separator style don't apply.

```
lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero)
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.separatorStyle = .none
    tv.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    tv.backgroundColor = .clear
    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        tv.dragDelegate = self
        tv.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        tv.dropDelegate = self
    }
    tv.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    tv.register(AddressCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    return tv
}()
```

init method, add table view to view

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

private func setupViews() {

    backgroundColor = .clear

    addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
                                 tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
                                 tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                                 tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)])
}
```

[image: Sample Image]

Can you describe to me, what I do wrong?

Comment: have you clear background color of cell?

Comment: I think you have set the `UITableViewCell` `backgroundColor` also to `.clear`

Comment: Yes, I set background color  clear to cell

Comment: change background like 
tableView.separatorStyle = .none
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear

Before this line => addSubview(tableView)

Comment: Kindly refer to this link http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/create-uitableview-programmatically-example-in-swift/

Comment: Did not help. I added this table view in custom uiview class, than I add this view to view controller. And when I try to change background color of table view from view controller, it works. But why it does not work in custom view?

Comment: Try setting `tableView.backgroundView = nil`

Comment: this did not help

Comment: You should show your full viewController code then. Might be something else.

Answer (score 0):

The separator style is to be set in layoutSubviews as it is being rendered while loading the cells. As for the background color. try setting it on `tv.contentView.backgroundColor`

Comment: this did not help